# Categorizing and Sorting Webform Submissions

Tags: 7, webforms, views

I'm trying to find an effective way to categorize and sort webform submissions. I already have them displaying in views, but would like to take it a bit further. Here's the goal:

Anonymous users can fill out an employment application on our site (via a webform). Our recruiter would like to be able to sort through these applications and do things such as categorize them (accepted, denied, etc.) by selecting multiple at once, and send batch emails to applicants.

I already have Views Bulk Operations installed, but it doesn't seem to play well with webform submissions, if at all. Does anyone know of a good way to accomplish this?

I'm on Drupal 7, using Views 7.x-3.6 and Webform 7.x-4.0-alpha6.

Answer (score 0):

[Webform Report](https://drupal.org/project/webform_report) module allows users to create simple, dynamic reports based on data collected by the webform module. It adds a new node type that contains the report criteria, and the data displayed is updated automatically as webforms are submitted. The data can be sorted according to the viewer's preference without altering the report criteria.

Comment: Webform Report does not allow you to send emails or perform any actions on the submissions. I'm looking to do things such as assign a status to each entry (approved, denied, etc) and send batch emails to the anonymous users who submitted the form (via the email they typed into the email field). The Webform Report module only displays the submissions and gives me an option to filter or download them. Not much more than views by itself can do.

Comment: Webform Report will do only the "Categorizing and Sorting Webform Submissions", it will not do automatically- you need to customize to your requirement and for your information from my knowledge there is no module will do your requirement using webform, I think the only module to support your spec is CRM module, have look on that.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use entityform instead of webforms module. with the subissions as entities there is the possibility to use bulk operations (VBO) on the submissions. You can use VBO to assign a status and also for sending emails via rules module.